# How to expand rows containing floated elements expand to 100% width?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working on a nav bar style. I want the border to expand to 100% width of the area the menu is taking up, but I want the elements in the rows to float to the right of this 100% width area. Unfortunately, if I get everything floated to the right then it doesn't expand to full width.

Here's an image to check out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu6i6.png
You can see what width it should be and what width things actually are.

Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="row">
    <nav class="top-bar-navigation">
        <div class="main-menu-holder">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Active</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button>CTA BUTTON</button>
        </div>
        <ul class="secondary-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Here's the SASS I've created for the nav element. There are some other styles for the default elements like typography but I don't think it's relevant to this issue:

```
.top-bar-navigation {
width: 100%;
clear: both;

.main-menu-holder {
    border-bottom: 2px solid $pale-grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-menu-holder,
.secondary-menu {
    float: right;
}

span,
button,
.main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
}

a.active {
    font-weight: 700;
}
}
```

Here is the Row style:

```
.row {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.row:after {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your section.row is applying padding or margins, but you haven't provided a complete enough set of the css rules, so it's impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: See the markup added above. Sorry I didn't add that the first time - my sass is really broken down into lots of small files, I only grabbed the code from the nav file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `<hr />` or creating a new `div` with a class on it to style it to create the same effect?

Comment: I could experiment with that, but ideally I'd like to find something that eliminates as much extraneous markup as possible. I'm building out elements for our style guide that will be used by a lot of different developers so the less code I can use the better.

Comment: @Ecobob that's the ticket! Thanks for your help :) - is there a way for me to mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: No worries mate :) I don't think you can do the comment, maybe the answer? Mmm...loving these rep points!